# Printing every number with a 3 within a range

Tags: python

User gives a range, say 0-31
Program should return a list that contains every number that has a 3;
So: 3,13,23,30,31

Should use a for loop statement, but I'm not too sure how to format it

```
for i in range(start, end+1):
    if 3 in i:
        print(i)
```

That's what I've got right now, appreciate the help!

edit:

```
def giveMeFive (start, end):
    everyfive=[]
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        if "5" in str(i):
            everyfive.append(i)
        return everyfive


    # Test giveMeFive()
beginning = int(input("Enter the starting value of the range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the ending value of the range: "))
fives = giveMeFive(beginning, end)

print("Here is the list of values that contain at least one 5:", fives)
print() # Insert a blank line in the output
```

Comment: `if 3 in i:` This should be `if 3 == i:`

Comment: No it shouldn't? He needs to find numbers that contain the number 3 - not equal it. It should be `3 in str(i)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def giveMeFive (start, end):
    fives = []
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        if "5" in str(i):
            fives.append(i)
    return fives

    # Test giveMeFive()
beginning = int(input("Enter the starting value of the range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the ending value of the range: "))
fives = giveMeFive(beginning, end)

print("Here is the list of values that contain at least one 5:", fives)
print() # Insert a blank line in the output
```

Comment: can't figure out how to comment code, but that's not working. It's just printing 3.

Comment: it's only printing the first number with a 3, not all of them

Comment: can you post the complete file that you are running? This prints out 3, 13, 23, and 30.

Comment: adding it to the original, post. actually printing numbers with a 5 anyways

Comment: when you return in a loop, the entire function will exit with that single value. You have to either print it from the loop or store it in a list.

Comment: how do I store it in a list

Comment: are you running the exact code? This is my trace: Enter the starting value of the range: 0
Enter the ending value of the range: 100
Here is the list of values that contain at least one 5: [5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 65, 75, 85, 95]

Comment: just copy and pasted the exact thing and got the same thing, [ ]

Comment: what values are you providing for the range?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add some explanations to @Testarific's answer. Your problem is that `i` is an integer type, in order to look up characters - which is a string type - in `i`, you need to first convert it to string type, which `str(i)` did.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question. Why not use list comprehension? Something like:

```
return [str(i) for i in range(0, 26) if "3" in str(i)]
```